# HyperLedger Composer: Unhandled Error

Tags: angularjs, hyperledger-composer

I get the following error in the HyperLedger Console:

```
 Browse your REST API at http://localhost:3000/explorer
    Unhandled error for request GET /bootstrap.min.css.map: Error: Cannot GET /bootstrap.min.css.map
        at raiseUrlNotFoundError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/loopback/server/middleware/url-not-found.js:21:17)
        at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
        at trim_prefix (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
        at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
        at Function.process_params (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
        at next (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
        at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:635:15
        at next (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:260:14)
        at Function.handle (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:174:3)
        at router (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:47:12)
        at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
        at trim_prefix (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
        at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
        at Function.process_params (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
        at next (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
        at urlencodedParser (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/urlencoded.js:91:7)
```

I get no error thrown by the Angular front-end upon submitting the form.

I am a newbie to both HyperLedger composer and Angular.

Please help.

Comment: hi there, haven't got enough info. What tutorial are you following?  Which version of Composer? Have you started the Angular app? Did you specify to connect to a running REST server - and is it actually running ? Can you also post your Node version and the output of `npm ls -g depth=0 ` thanks

Comment: Hi Paul,I am using the latest & greatest Composer version. I am not following any particular tutorial, but a custom application I am working on. My Composer Rest Server starts and works fine as I have tested the service using Swagger API tool. Angular application which I generated loads and works fine. This issue happens only when I try to submit a particular form. This is the only error message in the Composer Rest Server Console. Front end , I have checked the browser console and no errors. I am little puzzled myself too.

Comment: Are you multii-user and authentication for the REST server? Seen something [similar](https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/3949#issuecomment-385993737) reported here onwards...

Comment: I did found that link earlier and I tried updating the proxy.config file, I still have the same issue.

Comment: `Srisriss-MacBook-Pro:ra-network-fe reachsrisris$ npm ls -g --depth=0
/usr/local/lib
├── @angular/cli@6.0.8
├── composer-cli@0.19.11
├── composer-playground@0.19.7
├── composer-rest-server@0.19.11
├── generator-hyperledger-composer@0.19.11
├── lerna@2.11.0
├── npm@5.6.0
└── yo@2.0.2`

Comment: I can only assume you're trying to use the REST server multi-user (you've not said) - this issue probably captures what you're seeing (concerning COMPOSER_PROVIDERS not being set or set incorrectly, before launching the REST server). See also https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/integrating/enabling-rest-authentication.html

Comment: @PaulO'Mahony When I started Composer Rest Server, I did not choose Rest Authentication ON. At this time anyone can access my RestFul services as there is not authentication.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with the proxy configuration of the generated Angular app. I had the same issue and I was able to solve it by editing `proxy.conf.js` file located in the Angular app path.

Please refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52134203/7047189).