# REST client is stopped when angular application running

Tags: angular, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

In my application, I'm using a REST client and an Angular application generated by composer-cli. In sometimes, the REST client is terminated while I'm using the Angular app.

I noticed that this termination happens especially whenever I'm trying to use images in the Angular app. It seems an unwanted request is sent to the REST client when the image is loading.

REST client's log is as below.

[image]

I'm using a default generated Angular app. Any suggestions?

Comment: is that path correct `/asset/images/` should it be `/assets/...`, I have no idea to be honest just throwing  it out there

Comment: The path is correct. :-)

Comment: does it error on every image under that path? Does that file exist?

Comment: For every image in any location

Comment: The files are readable by the server? Correct permissions? Maybe the directories need proper permission? (going through my list of things I would check)

Comment: Been a while since I used express but I remember having to set extra config to serve static files@see https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Comment: Permissions are ok. Thank you btw :-)

Comment: Configuring for static files does not solve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue in my code. It was in the auto-generated proxy configuration file (proxy.conf.js).

```js
module.exports = [{
    context: ['/auth', '/api'],
    target,
    secure: true,
    changeOrigin: true
}, {
    context: '/',
    target,
    secure: true,
    changeOrigin: true,
    ws: true,
    bypass: function (req, res, proxyOptions) {
        const accept = req.headers.accept || '';
        if (accept.indexOf('html') !== -1) {
            return '/index.html';
        }
    }
}];
```

I changed above part to,

```js
module.exports = [{
    context: ['/auth', '/api'],
    target,
    secure: true,
    changeOrigin: true
}];
```

and also images should be located in `./src/assets` folder.

Comment: Nicely figured out